# How to generate stream of custom symbols instead of ints in lexer?

Tags: lex, symbols

I am asking for **gplex**, however it might be the case, the solution to the problem works for other lex-derived tools.

I wrote all rules, everything is fine with one exception. The type of the `scan` method of the generated scanner is `int`, and I would like to be `MySymbol` (which would consist of id of the token -- INT, STR, PLUS, so on, its value, and possible location in the file).

I checked the samples (not many of them), but they are very simplistic and just write out the fact rule was matched, I've read the manual, but it starts from parser perspective and for now I am a bit lost.

One of my rules in `lex` file:

```
while { return new MySymbol(MyTokens.WHILE); }
```

*All I have now is scanning phase, I have to finish it, and then I will think about parser.*

Comment: Have you looked at Chapter 4 of [The GPLEX Scanner Generator](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gplex/files/gplex.pdf)?  It looks like there is some useful guidance in that document.

Comment: @DavidGorsline, yes (I wrote I read it), however it is too obscure for me to understand how to switch the way `Scan` method works. What worries me, that the template gplex is based on, uses hardcoded `int Scan`. So still, I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yacc and Yacc-like tools (here GPLex) relies on side effect. Normally you could think of returning the data, but here you are returning token id, and any extra data has to be "passed" via special variables like `yyval`.